# Incorrect fraction division in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I'm doing a [tutorial on algorithms](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html)

One of the exercises is to create a fraction class that can take a negative denominator and still correctly present the results. However, when I'm dividing I'm still getting negative output:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num, denom):
        if isinstance(num, int) or isinstance(denom, int):
            common = gcd(num, abs(denom))
            self._num = num//common
            self._denom = abs(denom)//common
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d / %d" % (self._num, self._denom)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        denum = self._num * other._num
        div = self._denom * other._denom
        return Fraction(denum, div)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        temp_fraction = Fraction(other._denom, other._num)
        return self.__mul__(temp_fraction)

def gcd(a, b):
    while(b):
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Fraction(-4, -5) / Fraction(-1, -2)) 
    print(Fraction(-4, 5) / Fraction(-1, 2))
    # Both output -8 / 5, should be 8 / 5
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit** I've corrected my code and rewrote some erroneous assertions in my doctest. All test pass now!

Full code:

```
from fractions import gcd

class Fraction:
    """
    Checking if instantiating a fraction works
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2))
    1 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2))
    -1 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction('Foo', 'Bar'))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    TypeError

    Adding a fraction to another fraction
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(1, 4))
    3 / 4
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2) + Fraction(2, 2))
    1 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 5) + Fraction(-1, 5))
    -2 / 5
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, -5) + Fraction(-1, -5))
    2 / 5

    Substracting a fraction from another
    >>> print(Fraction(3, 4) - Fraction(1, 4))
    1 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2) - Fraction(1, 4))
    -3 / 4
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, 10) - Fraction(-1, 10))
    -1 / 10
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, -10) - Fraction(-1, -10))
    1 / 10

    Multiplying 2 fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 5) * Fraction(1, 2))
    1 / 10
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2) * Fraction(1, 4))
    -1 / 8
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2) * Fraction(-1, 8))
    1 / 16
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, -2) * Fraction(-1, -8))
    1 / 16

    Dividing 2 fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 4) / Fraction(1, 2))
    1 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction(-1, 2) / Fraction(1, 15))
    -15 / 2
    >>> print(Fraction(-4, 5) / Fraction(-1, 2))
    8 / 5
    >>> print(Fraction(-4, -5) / Fraction(-1, -2))
    8 / 5

    Equality between fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) == Fraction(2, 4))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) == Fraction(1, 3))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, 4) == Fraction(-1, 2))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, -4) == Fraction(-1, -2))
    True

    Non-equality between fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) != Fraction(64, 128))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 4) != Fraction(999, 4000))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(-3, 4) != Fraction(-3, 5))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(-3, -4) != Fraction(-3, -5))
    True

    Larger size difference between fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) > Fraction(857, 1713))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) > Fraction(857, 1715))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 338) >= Fraction(2, 676))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, 5) > Fraction(-1, 5))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(-2, -5) > Fraction(-1, -5))
    True

    Smaller size difference between fractions
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) < Fraction(857, 1713))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 2) < Fraction(857, 1715))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(1, 338) <= Fraction(2, 676))
    True
    >>> print(Fraction(-3, 7) < Fraction(-6, 7))
    False
    >>> print(Fraction(-3, -7) < Fraction(-6, -7))
    True
    """
    def __init__(self, num, denom):
        if isinstance(num, int) and isinstance(denom, int):
            common = gcd(num, denom)
            self._num = num//common
            self._denom = denom//common
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d / %d" % (self._num, self._denom)

    def __add__(self, other):
        denum = (self._num * other.get_denom()) + (other.get_num() * self._denom)
        div = (self._denom * other.get_denom())
        return Fraction(denum, div)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        denum = (self._num * other.get_denom()) - (other.get_num() * self._denom)
        div = (self._denom * other.get_denom())
        return Fraction(denum, div)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        denum = self._num * other.get_num()
        div = self._denom * other.get_denom()
        return Fraction(denum, div)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        temp_fraction = Fraction(other.get_denom(), other.get_num())
        return self.__mul__(temp_fraction)

    def eq_denum(self, other):
        first = self._num * other.get_denom()
        last = other.get_num() * self._denom
        return first, last

    def __eq__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first == last

    def __ne__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first != last

    def __gt__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first > last

    def __ge__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first >= last

    def __lt__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first < last

    def __le__(self, other):
        first, last = self.eq_denum(other)
        return first <= last

    def get_num(self):
        return self._num

    def get_denom(self):
        return self._denom


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Use abs(number) to remove the sign.

Comment: I'm already doing that to the denominator, the problem wih the numerator is that -x div -x doesn't equals a positive number in this example.

Comment: If you want to raise the TypeError exception if one of your arguments is NOT an integer, your if statement in Fraction.__init__() should use an **and** statement instead of **or**, because you want *both* of them to be integers. Ideally though, you really shouldn't be checking - Python heavily prefers [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). This means that instead of checking types all the time, you should just attempt to do what you want to do and deal with the exception if/when it occurs. Check out the second paragraph of the Wikipedia entry I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with division but with how you use your `gcd` function in `__init__`.

It seems you just have to *remove* all those `abs` when you create the fraction. This way, the `gcd` will be negative if `denom` is negative, and you get the desired behaviour.

```
if isinstance(num, int) and isinstance(denom, int):
    common = gcd(num, denom)
    self._num = num//common
    self._denom = denom//common
```

Some examples:

```
                            # with abs    # without abs
print(Fraction( 4,  6))     #  2/3           2/3
print(Fraction( 4, -6))     #  2/3          -2/3
print(Fraction(-4,  6))     # -2/3          -2/3
print(Fraction(-4, -6))     # -2/3           2/3
```

Also, note that *both* numbers should be ints, not just one of them (use `and`).

Comment: Tnx! I did this before, but my doctests failed. Turned out, I just made some assertion errors.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the **__str__** to:

```
return "%d / %d" % (abs(self._num), abs(self._denom))
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem. How would this print `Fraction(-1, 2)`?